# Reporting using XML data sources -- what tool/language should I use?

Tags: xml, reporting

I have a bunch of XML data that I'd like use as a data source for some web-based reports.  I'm using Reporting Services right now, but I don't really like their report designer very much.  I'd like to customize things a little more and be able to generate graphs and charts and make them semi-interactive (allow for sorting, tool-tips, etc).

What tools/libraries are available for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our [Data Dynamics Reports product](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/) has sophisticated support for building a report from XML data. For example, since we use XPath expressions to select nodes to bind the fields in the report to, you can bind to data with complex relationships in XML. [This walkthrough in our documentation](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ddReports/ddrwlkXMLData.html) walks you through binding data to XML.

There area screencasts that show more about the product [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/Default.aspx#screencasts). We also have [this screencast](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/ScreencastViewer.aspx?ID=DSXML) that shows a little bit about working with XML data and how you can let end users create reports from XML data using our end user designer control. This one shows how you can embed the end user designer control into your application and the end user can design a report without knowing or understanding XML at all.

I hope this is helpful, let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Telerik's services or maybe Crystal Reports

Comment: Crystal Reports costs an absolute fortune and editing an existing report is pain beyond belief. 30 dollars PER USER PER MONTH! http://www.crystalreports.com/learnmore.asp         from that site: Reports: Unlimited ***        *** Usage levels subject to change without notice!!!! what the ???!!!!!

Comment: But vg1890 didn't ask for free options. Most reporting solutions are pricey, we can all agree on that. However, some companies would rather purchase a reporting solution like Crystal instead of developing their own.